# Do enemies in Void Bastards respawn? Can I make it stop?

Tags: void-bastards

While playing Void Bastards I noticed that there were no one after I killed everybody in a room. After a few minutes, I returned to that room and there were some a janitor or tourist (can't remember) there, even after I locked surrounding doors.

Do they respawn after some time? Is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Fandom wiki :

> Biological enemies can spawn infinitely from various rifts throughout the ships, but mechanical enemies like Secbots and Turrets only appear in limited quantities per ship and do not respawn. Certain enemies like Tydybots and Pirates will only appear on a ship under specific circumstances.

Rifts looks like this :[image: Rift]

Sealing the doors of the room where the rift is seems the only way to deal with it.

Comment: Please, to make the answer complete, could you explain what Rifts are (maybe add a picture)?